OpenAPI generate creates duplicate models and classes when $ref is being used
I'm working on a Kotlin Spring Boot project using Gradle, and I'm having trouble with OpenAPI Generator.
App - app.yaml (a ref to shared.yaml is given to a schema component)
Shared - shared.yaml
When openApi Generate is executed on app.yaml it generated duplicate class and models from shared.yaml in my app package. Shared.yaml model classes are already there in shared app.
Here’s what I’ve tried so far:
I attempted to use importMappings in the OpenAPI Generator configuration to map the widget reference to the lib model, but instead of referring to the existing class, it ends up creating a new class in the specified package.
I also tried disabling model generation for specific classes using configOptions.put("modelsToGenerate", "OtherModels") and generateModels.set(false), but OpenAPI still generates the model.
Is there a way to completely exclude certain models from being generated and instead reference an existing model from another module?
